# rdiff-backup increment contents (files added, removed, updated, etc.)

Tags: version-control, backup, rsync, rdiff-backup

I haven't found any obvious answer to that question in the rdiff-backup documentation: is there a simple way to list the changes included in a given increment, i.e. which files/folders have been added, removed, updated, etc.? I'm not necessarily interested in the details of those changes (i.e. what was changed in a given file).

When I run the following command:

rdiff-backup --list-increments backup

I get a list of increments. For example:

"Found 3 increments:
    increment3...
    increment2...
    increment1...
 Current mirror: ..."

I can list the changes included in the latest increment (increment3) by running the following command:

rdiff-backup --list-changed-since time backup

by choosing the adequate "time" value.

But what if I want to see what changes are contained in increment2 only?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a directory named `rdiff-backup-data` in your destination backup folder which contains a lot of interesting stuff including files named like `file_statistics.2011-04-08T16:50:20+03:00.data.gz` which do have information about the files changed.